# I can't run commands in cmd access denied as administrator

Tags: access-denied

as administrator I cannot execute commands in cmd, access denied, nor does it allow me to run gpedit, change settings on network adapters, or change permissions on any folder.

Comment: have you tried running cmd as administrator? if you have a cmd window open you should be able to right click the taskbar icon and choose run-as-admin.. from the right click menu

Answer (score -1):

1. Click Windows button and write "command"
2. Then you'll get "Run as administration".

[image]